# Neo4j LOAD CSV cannot match and create relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I was going through the tutorial examples in the LOAD CSV movies examples while applying it to my project's test data.
(I'm attempting to follow the sample code here:
https://neo4j.com/docs/getting-started/current/cypher-intro/load-csv/)

I'm trying to create relationships between each article's keywords, and in turn find other articles with some of the same keywords.

A representation of my test data csv files is as follows:
CSV used to create all title nodes:

```
title_id,title  
T1,Article Title 1  
T2,Article Title 2
```

CSV that I want to use to create the relationships:

```
title_id,keyword_id,keyword  
T1,K1,aaa  
T1,K2,bbb  
T1,K3,ccc  
T1,K4,ddd  
T2,K1,aaa  
T2,K5,eee  
T2,K6,fff  
T2,K4,ddd
```

First, I attempted to create the title nodes using the code below:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///1209_tet_titles.csv" AS csvLine1
WITH csvLine1
WHERE csvLine1.title_id IS NOT NULL
MERGE (a_title:title{t_id:csvLine1.title_id,Title:csvLine1.title})
```

Then, I attempted to create the individual keyword nodes alongside the relationships using the code below:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///1209test_titleid_kwid_kw.csv" AS csvLine3
WITH csvLine3
WHERE csvLine3.title_id IS NOT NULL
MERGE(keywords:Keyword{k_id:csvLine3.keyword_id,Keyword:csvLine3.keyword})
WITH csvLine3
MATCH(title:Title{id:csvLine3.title_id}),(keyword:Keyword{id:csvLine3.keyword_id)})
CREATE (title)-[r1:HAS_KEYWORDS]->(keyword)
```

The nodes are successfully created, but the match command finds nothing, and thus no relationships are created. At this stage I'm not sure what the difference is between my situation and the movies example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like just a small typo at fault here.

In your MERGE, you're merging in the `k_id` property, but in your MATCH you're matching to an `id` property, which doesn't exist. If you changed this to `k_id` then you should see it succeed.

That said, there's no need to re-match to the node you just created, since you can just keep the variable in scope and use that when you create the relationship:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///1209test_titleid_kwid_kw.csv" AS csvLine3
WITH csvLine3
WHERE csvLine3.title_id IS NOT NULL
MERGE (keyword:Keyword{k_id:csvLine3.keyword_id, Keyword:csvLine3.keyword})
WITH csvLine3, keyword
MATCH (title:Title{t_id:csvLine3.title_id})
CREATE (title)-[:HAS_KEYWORDS]->(keyword)
```

Comment: Good catch, looks like I made the same kind of mistake! Query fixed.